# updating single row in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mongodb, nosql, sharding, memcached

We have a situation where we need to update on a single row several thousands time a second and this requirement lasts continuously for 5 hours every day due to the nature of the business. Design cannot be changed so we are looking for solutions. Usually we use very fast SSD drives for faster performance and so far we are able to cope up with the requests. 
But our traffic is increasing every day and we need another solution that can replace our current method and help us update same row many more thousands of time a second.

Any suggestion would be great. We use MYSQL 5.6 currently

Comment: You do not give much details, but think about doing thousands of updates in memory (engine=memory table or even outside of mysql) and only syncing to "permanent" table once per second/after 1k updates or something similar.

Comment: you've added `mamcached` tag. i think it's a way to go.

Comment: Are you updating a counter?  Hundreds of counters?  Do you need transactional integrity?  Please elaborate -- there is no simple solution; we need to discuss workarounds.

Comment: Actually the row updates everytime patient pays money or we refund money to patient.that row is our company account you can say.so we cannot find any logic to split that row yet.

Comment: Ok, so you need as much integrity as possible.. You should add this and more to the question. You could have multiple accounts - for incoming/outgoing, or by place..

Comment: actually separate accounts is not going to solve the problem, credit to our account is not a problem it is mostly debits. Because we are group of hospitals and we discharge patients daily at a specific time so thousands of queries start hitting that row for few hours, credits happen all day so they are spread out evenly but debit happens altogether and we cannot find any alternative logic

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the MEMORY storage engine, so the changes will happen in memory. In case of a crash, you can rely on the binlog to recover the latest value. And if you have a slave, you can use InnoDB on the slave.

If you want to stay on InnoDB, consider the HandlerSocket plugin. It provides an SQL-less interface to InnoDB, and it should be much faster in your scenario.